# How can I check all child items when the main head is checked and vice-versa?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, dropdown

I am making a dropdown list in which I want to select all the sub-items if the main head is checked, and select the head, if all the sub-items are checked.

```
const DropDownList = ({ data }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState({});
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState({});

  const handleClick = (department) => {
    setOpen((prevOpen) => ({
      ...prevOpen,
      [department]: !prevOpen[department],
    }));
  };

  const handleCheck = (item) => {
    setChecked((prevChecked) => ({
      ...prevChecked,
      [item]: !prevChecked[item],
    }));
  };

  return (
    <List>
      {data.map((department) => (
        <React.Fragment key={department.department}>
          <ListItem
            sx={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
            onClick={() => handleClick(department.department)}
          >
            <Checkbox
              checked={checked[department.department] || false}
              onChange={() => handleCheck(department.department)}
            />
            <ListItemText primary={department.department} />
            {open[department.department] ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
          </ListItem>
          <Collapse in={open[department.department]} unmountOnExit>
            <List
              component="div"
              sx={{ padding: "0 35px", cursor: "pointer" }}
              disablePadding
            >
              {department.sub_departments.map((subDepartment) => (
                <ListItem key={subDepartment}>
                  <Checkbox
                    checked={checked[subDepartment] || false}
                    onChange={() => handleCheck(subDepartment)}
                  />
                  <ListItemText primary={subDepartment} />
                </ListItem>
              ))}
            </List>
          </Collapse>
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </List>
  );
};

export default DropDownList;
```

This is my List component.

I know the logic, but I can't implement it. I don't know how to. I know that by checking if all sub-items are checked, we can check the head too, but I don't know how to implement this bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For "select all the sub-items if the main head is checked", consider modifying `handleCheck()` to pass an `item` object. This will let us know of the checked item's `sub_departments`:

```
const handleCheck = (item) => {
  setChecked((prevChecked) => ({
    ...prevChecked,
    [item.department]: !prevChecked[item.department],
  }));
};
…
<Checkbox
  …
  onChange={() => handleCheck(department)}
/>
…
<Checkbox
  …
  onChange={() => handleCheck({ department: subDepartment })}
/>
```

If it is being checked, check its `sub_departments`:

```js
const handleCheck = (item, parent = {}) => {
  setChecked((prevChecked) => {
    const list = {
      ...prevChecked,
      [item.department]: !prevChecked[item.department],
    };

    if (list[item.department]) {
      if (item.sub_departments) {
        item.sub_departments.forEach(sub => {
          list[sub] = true;
        });
      }
    }

    return list;
  });
};
```

For "select the head, if all the sub-items are checked", pass in the parent department item as a second argument to `handleCheck()`:

```
const handleCheck = (item, parent = {}) => {
  …
}
…
<Checkbox
  …
  onChange={() => handleCheck({ department: subDepartment }, department)}
/>
```

Then check the parent department if all the `sub_departments` are checked:

```js
const handleCheck = (item, parent = {}) => {
  setChecked((prevChecked) => {
    const list = {
      ...prevChecked,
      [item.department]: !prevChecked[item.department],
    };

    if (list[item.department]) {
      …
      if (parent.sub_departments && parent.sub_departments.length) {
        let checkParent = true;

        for (const subItem of parent.sub_departments) {
          if (!list[subItem]) {
            checkParent = false;
            break;
          }
        }

        if (checkParent) {
          list[parent.department] = true;
        }
      }
    }

    return list;
  });
};
```

Full example:

```js
const { useState } = React;
const { List, ListItem, Checkbox, ListItemText, Collapse } = MaterialUI;

const ExpandMore = () => 'ExpandMore';
const ExpandLess = () => 'ExpandLess';

const DropDownList = ({ data }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState({});
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState({});

  const handleClick = (department) => {
    setOpen((prevOpen) => ({
      ...prevOpen,
      [department]: !prevOpen[department],
    }));
  };

  const handleCheck = (item, parent = {}) => {
    setChecked((prevChecked) => {
      const list = {
        ...prevChecked,
        [item.department]: !prevChecked[item.department],
      };
      
      if (list[item.department]) {
        if (item.sub_departments) {
          item.sub_departments.forEach(sub => {
            list[sub] = true;
          });
        }
 
        if (parent.sub_departments && parent.sub_departments.length) {
          let checkParent = true;

          for (const subItem of parent.sub_departments) {
            if (!list[subItem]) {
              checkParent = false;
              break;
            }
          }
          
          if (checkParent) {
            list[parent.department] = true;
          }
        }
      }
      
      return list;
    });
  };

  return (
    <List>
      {data.map((department) => (
        <React.Fragment key={department.department}>
          <ListItem
            sx={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
            onClick={() => handleClick(department.department)}
          >
            <Checkbox
              checked={checked[department.department] || false}
              onChange={() => handleCheck(department)}
            />
            <ListItemText primary={department.department} />
            {open[department.department] ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
          </ListItem>
          <Collapse in={open[department.department]} unmountOnExit>
            <List
              component="div"
              sx={{ padding: "0 35px", cursor: "pointer" }}
              disablePadding
            >
              {department.sub_departments.map((subDepartment) => (
                <ListItem key={subDepartment}>
                  <Checkbox
                    checked={checked[subDepartment] || false}
                    onChange={() => handleCheck({ department: subDepartment }, department)}
                  />
                  <ListItemText primary={subDepartment} />
                </ListItem>
              ))}
            </List>
          </Collapse>
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </List>
  );
};


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(
  <DropDownList
    data={[
      {
        department: 'Fruit',
        sub_departments: ['apple', 'pear', 'orange'],
      },
      {
        department: 'Colors',
        sub_departments: ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue'],
      },
    ]}
  />
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@mui/material@v5.14.1/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: your example does not work as expected :/

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Consider providing more details in your question to disambiguate your expectations.

Comment: @Wongin it is not my question I juste read it and tried your code in snippet

Comment: Ah, my mistake @Hatana. Consider reading the question again. The solution I provided solves the problems outlined in the question: "to select all the sub-items if the main head is checked" and "select the head, if all the sub-items are checked".

Comment: but when you uncheck Fruit its childrens does not uncheck also when you unckeck children the parent does not uncheck*

Comment: Indeed; that behavior is not specified in the question and thus has not been implemented in the answer. I feel like it would be unreasonable to expect functionality not stipulated in the question.

Comment: Thanks @Wongjn! I tried what you said, and with little bit of help from other sources, I was able to achieve my target!